# Почему запускается два раза componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Не могу понять, почему запускается два раза componentDidMount?

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
    console.log("constructor");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render');
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Тест </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте удалить тег `<StrictMode>` или `<React.StrictMode>` из index.js.

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло)